# Choice of Gerund or infinitive as subject of a sentence

Tags: grammaticality

In a multiple choice exercise I had to choose between:

.................... is banned in all pubs in Ireland.

A/ To smoke  B/ Smoking

I'm pretty sure the solution is B (Smoking) but I don't really know the rule behind. Could somebody please explain why it is B (if so)?

Answer (score 3):

The immediate reason is not a general principle of English grammar, but the particular requirements of the verb *ban*.

*Ban* has two subcategorisation frames:

> They banned smoking
>
> They banned him from smoking

But **They banned [him] to smoke* is not grammatical, whether the 'him' is there or not.

Other words have their own patterns, which are similar in some ways, different in others:

> They allow smoking.
>
> They allow him to smoke.

but not

> *They allow to smoke.

So in this case, the infinitive is permitted, but not as the direct object: there must be a direct object (a person).

So the answer to your question is that "To smoke is banned" is not grammatical, because *ban* does not allow an infinitive as its direct object.

One further point: when a verb does accept an infinitive as its direct object, it always seems to mean the specific case of the speaker. So *I want to smoke* means that I want **me** to smoke (though we almost never express the *me*). Not many verbs seem to accept either an infinitive or an *-ing*, but one that does is *expect*, and there you can see the difference in meaning:

> I expect to smoke.

means that I expect that I shall smoke, while

> I expect smoking.

means that I expect that people will be smoking, not necessarily me.